# JavaScript TouchEvent did not work

Tags: javascript, html, touchstart

Recently I started play with TouchEvent. 
I would like to ask why this code does not work.
Why DIV "coords" does not display any result.
I used the code from:https://mobiforge.com/design-development/html5-mobile-web-touch-events

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang ="pl-PL">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

<style>
#touchzone{
width:300px;
height:300px;
border:1px solid #aaaaaa;


}


</style>
 
</head>

 
<body>
<div id="coords"></div>
 <div id="touchzone"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
function init() {
  var touchzone = document.getElementById("touchzone");
  touchzone.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, false);
  
}

}


function touchHandler(event) {
  var coords = document.getElementById("coords");
  coords.innerHTML = 'x: ' + event.touches[0].pageX + ', y: ' + event.touches[0].pageY;
  
}

</script>

 </body>


</html>
```

Comment: Touchstart does not give any coordinate data, only touchmove does.

Comment: Touchstart supported coordinate data in the past, but no longer now

Comment: If I change Touchstart on touchmove. 
The program will work?